# module error in code. Cannot figure out what is wrong

Tags: python, nlp

I am getting error in my following code. I cant figure out what is wrong in this. Please help.

```
from nltk.corpus import stopwords 
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize  
import tqdm

stop_words = set(stopwords.words('english'))   
text_final = []
post_processed_text = X['combined']
filtered_sentence=[]

for words in tqdm(range(len(post_processed_text))):
    post_processed_text[words] = str(post_processed_text[words])

for words in tqdm(post_processed_text):
    word_tokens = word_tokenize(words)   
    filtered_sentence = [w for w in word_tokens if not w in stop_words]
    text_final.append(' '.join(filtered_sentence))

post_processed_text = text_final
```

I am getting an error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-21-076ead03255a> in <module>()
      8 filtered_sentence=[]
      9 
---> 10 for words in tqdm(range(len(post_processed_text))):
     11     post_processed_text[words] = str(post_processed_text[words])
     12 

TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

I tried changing names of every variable but still i cant understand what is wrong. Please help

Comment: You cannot call `tqdm(...)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be using predefined module as a variable name.

The problem here is

```
import tqdm
```

This will import tqdm module. You have to import it as follows

```
from tqdm import tqdm
```